# Could not get unknown property 'mavenUser' for Credentials

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

All I am getting following error in **build.gradle** in Android Studio :

```
Could not get unknown property 'mavenUser' for Credentials
        [username: null] of type
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated
```

Below my **Gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {


                // ~/.gradle/gradle.properties should be configured!
                credentials {
                    username mavenUser
                    password mavenPassword
                }
                url 'http://dev.softwerk.se:8080/nexus/content/repositories/softwerk-repo'
            }
        }

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 19
            buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 8
                targetSdkVersion 19
                versionCode 2014020601
                versionName "2.0.0"
            }

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'

            // Sync framework
            compile 'se.softwerk.commons.android:android-framework:1.1.10@aar'
            compile 'com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.0'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
            compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.1'
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a file called `gradle.properties` in your project directory. Add the lines:

```
mavenUser=yourusername
mavenPassword=yourpassword
```

Comment: publishing your password in the repo doesn't look like a safe choice

Comment: mavenUser=$yourusername
mavenPassword=$yourpassword

and then expose these variables via the safest way from whichever execution flow/tool is being used

Answer (score 1):

1. For me it works I have add this official doc generated username and password in settings.gradle file under mavenCentral() write this username and password with
   proper use of = ' '

   [image: for first change]

   ```
   username='paypal_sgerritz'
   password='AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
   ```
2. Add this username and password in gradle.properties file with proper use of = ' '

   ```
   username='paypal_sgerritz'
   password='AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to edit my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file and add the credentials in it.

1. Open the properties file using -> `vim ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`
2. Add your credentials something like below and save it.

> user=abc_user
> password=abc_password

Rerun your build.

Answer (score 0):

I have to spend sometime solving this problem even with the `mavenUser` and `mavenPassword` in `gradle.properties`, later figured out that the key names are case sensivite, so please make sure that both key names `mavenUser` and `mavenPassword` are mentioned as it is with matching key names in `gradle.properties` or `settings.gradle` files